# Can I change properties of one screen when on another in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

If I have a xaml file like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="wordGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="false"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

In the OnAppearing of a .cs file associated with a xaml file I know I can set a property like this:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        wordGrid.IsVisible = false;
```

However is there a way that I could set the wordGrid to be visible in another .cs that is associated with another xaml file?

Comment: can you explain more what you are trying to do? You can do but before answering I would like to understand why you are trying to set visible on something that is not currently visible. Are you trying to set this before you navigate to that screen from another screen?

Comment: I have a setting screen that I use to set parts of the main screen visible or not.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I assume user doesn't go to main screen every time? Then you have to store these settings permanently. You Settings plugin to store the data. If user need to set these settings every time you can use in memory class to store settings

Comment: @YuriS - What is the Settings plugin ? I can store them permanently but how should I set properties on the main screen to visible.  Should I set them directly from the settings page or should I check the settings when I open the main screen?

Comment: You can use other plugins or packages even write your own but here is the good one. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin When user sets parameters in main screen store them and when you load your main screen or other screen read them and apply. Set some default for the first time user opens main screen

Comment: You can use Messaging Center. Take a look at it.

Comment: In this case messaging center will not help as the target page is not  constructed yet

Answer (score 0):

Expose a public property for the `wordGrid` field in your code behind .cs file:

```
...
public Grid WordGrid {
    get { return wordGrid; }
    set { wordGrid = value; }
}
...
```

This will work just fine, but any larger and maintainable application will benefit from doing this with `{Binding}` and proper mvvm.